# Daemons and runlevels Linux

Tags: linux

Linux
In class they ask me this and we have not given it and also the notes are out of date using chkconfig for example, I can't find a way to solve it.

3. Make it impossible to use the printer in runlevel 2, for this you must ensure that its daemon (cups) does not run when entering that level.
4. Make that for level # 5, the cron daemon will not run.

I need an explanation of this because I can't access the level, I just get it to work as a service, thanks guys!!

Comment: Runlevels are not used in modern Linux systems.

Comment: Voting to close the question as off topic. We don't do your homework here.

Answer (score 0):

chkconfig is now obsolete, it was probably for RHEL 5 or 6.

Most current distros now use Systemd (use the systemctl command), and the concept of runlevels have been superseded by Systemd targets.

I hope this gives you a hint in solving your homework.

Comment: The first and second I have finally taken it out, but number 3 I can't do it no matter what I try, because I know how to stop the service but I can't stop it right at that level.really what I need is a short but accurate explanation